# Use SQL Login for Synchronizing AG Logins

Tags: availability-group

I have a script that I typically use to sync AG logins.  However, I need to implement it to run automatically using SQL Credential and Password.  Does anyone know how I can adjust the below script to use a SQL login and password?

```
Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup -SqlInstance 'My-AG' | Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup -Exclude SpConfigure, CustomErrors, Credentials, DatabaseMail, LinkedServers `
    , LoginPermissions, SystemTriggers, DatabaseOwner, AgentCategory, AgentOperator, AgentAlert, AgentProxy, AgentSchedule
```

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms you're using.